# Sending object to Servlet throws an error I cant resolve

Tags: java, servlets, applet

I am sending a string from an Applet to a Servlet. When I go to get the output stream from the URLConnection I get the exception thrown **java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support output**

*Some background info; I am using Eclipse, I tested the applet by running it in eclipse & in my own html page I made & they throw the same error. I have downloaded the correct Java Web SDK. Maybe I need to set up my hxxp://8008... server?*

Why is this happening & how can I fix it? Do I need to sign my applet to make it work?

Here is my code & I have commented where the exception is thrown:

```
public String messageServlet()
{
    try
    {
        URLConnection conn = connectToServlet();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();  // Exception thrown here: UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support output
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream( out );
        objOut.writeObject( message );
        objOut.flush();
        objOut.close();

        System.out.println( "1" ); 

        // receive result from servlet
        InputStream instr = conn.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();
        System.out.println( "1" );
        return result;
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "In messageServlet(): " + e );
        msgBox.setText( msgBox.getText() + "\nIn messageServlet(): " + e );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( "In messageServlet(): " + e );
        msgBox.setText( msgBox.getText() + "\nIn messageServlet(): " + e );
    }

    return null;
}

public URLConnection connectToServlet()
{
    try
    {
        URL servletUrl = new URL( getCodeBase(), "echo" );
        URLConnection conn = servletUrl.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput( true );
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object" );

        return conn;
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "In connectToServlet(): " + e );
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: from the doc : ... the application is attempting to write to a read-only URL connection. I think you have to set up your server before. This code is working with a valid one.

Comment: How do I set up my connection to not be read-only? Is this something I can do in Java or is it something to do with my actual internet connection?

Comment: Could you print your URL? If it is some type of `file:` URL, it of course can't work. If it is a `http:` URL, it should work (or you would get a better error message).

Comment: Thanks for the comment: yeah my URL=file:/C:/Users/Print/Desktop/TestApplet/bin/. I feel kindof stupid but how can I get it to http:....? I know I could just write "http://..." but I want something dynamic

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Changing the connection to URL servletUrl = new URL( "hxxp://localhost:8008/" ); causes this error " java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Answer (score 1):

You've two potential problems:

1. Webserver isn't started. Ensure that it is started and that http://localhost:8008/context/servleturl works fine in your webbrowser.
2. You used the wrong URL. The [`hxxp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hxxp) scheme makes no sense. It's [`http`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

---

Apart from this all, the common practice is to *not* hardcode the base domain in your applet, it would make it unportable (you would need to fix/change it everytime when you move domains). Just obtain it from the inherited [`Applet#getCodeBase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) method. Use this as base for your servlet URL.

```
URL servlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "servleturl");
// ...
```

*Here `getCodeBase()` thus returns like http://localhost:8008/context*.

---

Again apart from this all, I'd prefer sending plaintext, JSON or XML format over HTTP above Java-specific binary data. It's better reuseable and easier to pre/postprocess. You have some characters in a String which you'd like to send forth and back. Just send it as HTTP request parameter and let the servlet grab it by `request.getParameter()` and so on. Why would you ever use Java serialization for this?