# Protocol error trying to communicate applet to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, applet, client-server

I face "java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support output" problem when I sent my name from applet to servlet.
I tried [Sending object to Servlet throws an error I cant resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950874/sending-object-to-servlet-throws-an-error-i-cant-resolve) but it didn't solve my problem.
My applet code is:

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class AppletToServlet extends HttpServlet {
// Getting a String object from the applet and send it back.
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream inputFromApplet = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            String string = (String) inputFromApplet.readObject();
// getting string value and passing to applet
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(string);
objectOutputStream.flush();
objectOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the servlet code is:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AppletToServletExample extends Applet {
  private TextField inputField = new TextField(10);
  private TextField resultField = new TextField(10);

  public void init() {
    // add input label, field and send button
    add(new Label("Input Your Name", Label.RIGHT));
    add(inputField);
    Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    add(sendButton);
    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SendData();
      }
    });
    // add output label as a non editable field
    add(new Label("Output:", Label.RIGHT));
    add(resultField);
    resultField.setEditable(false);
  }

  // Get a connection to the servlet.
  private URLConnection getServletConnection() throws MalformedURLException,
      IOException {
    URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "applettoservlet");
    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-java-serialized-object");
    return con;
  }

  // Send the inputField data to the servlet and show the result in the
  // outputField.
  private void SendData() {
    try {
      String input = inputField.getText();
      // send data to the servlet
      URLConnection con = getServletConnection();
      OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
      oos.writeObject(input);
      oos.flush();
      oos.close();
      // receive result from servlet
      InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
      ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(
          inputStream);
      String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
      inputFromServlet.close();
      inputStream.close();
      // show result
      resultField.setText(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I searched practically everywhere but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you run the applet? Did you actually embed it onto a page and request it over a webserver of some kind?

The code

```
 URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "applettoservlet");
```

will only work as expected if you're running the applet from a page served by a web/application-server.
Try adding

```
System.out.println(urlServlet);
```

to check what url is beeing used.

Comment: no I am trying to run it on neatbeans applet viewer.
not in browser.
what to do then?

Comment: I suppose there are more elegant ways to do this, but i would hardcode the url to the server for testing. 
Replace 
`URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "applettoservlet");`
with
`URL urlServlet = new URL("http://myappserver/myServletPath/applettoserver");`

Comment: it remove the protocol issue but there is still error. I think this is because I am giving the path the wrong way. My web project name is "applet" and these two classes are present inside it under "<default package>". I rewrote your code as "URL urlServlet = new URL("htp://applet/AppletToServlet");" but it still gives an error "java.net.UnknownHostException: AppletToServlet" What am I missing?

Comment: if someone could solve my problem. I would be very thankful

Comment: It's getting more and more obvious that you have no idea what you're doing. You're trying to create a servlet and an applet. Therefor you need an application server (for the servlet), i.e. Apache Tomcat. After having installend the application server and deployed the servlet (the class that extends HTTPServlet) you'd have a internet-like url "http://localhost/appletToServlet" that you could use in the applet.

Comment: I do have Apache Tomcat installed in neatbeans

Comment: now it is giving this error "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Comment: Try this: Copy the url that the applet is trying to reach into your clipboard and paste it into a browser. If there is no response in the browser, the application server is not running (or running on another port, or you have firewall problems).